# Python regex: finding sequence of chars inside a string

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm using python and regex (new to both) to find sequence of chars in a string as follows:
Grab the first instance of p followed by any number (It'll always be in the form of p_ _ where _ and _ will be integers). Then either find an 's' or a 'go' then all integers till the end of the string. For example:

ascjksdcvy**p12**nbvnzxcm**go**nbmbh**12**hjg**23**

should yield p12 go 12 23.

ascjksdcvy**p12**nbvnzxcm**s**nbmbh**12**hjg**23**

should yield p12 s 12 23.

I've only managed to get the p12 part of the string and this is what I've tried so far to extract the 'go' or 's':

```
decoded = (re.findall(r'([p][0-9]*)',myStr))
print(decoded) //prints p12
```

I know by doing something like

`re.findall(r'[s]|[go]',myStr)`

will give me all occurrences of s and g and o, but something like that is not what I'm looking for. And I'm not sure how I'd combine these regexes to get the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `re.findall` with pattern grouping:

```
>>> string = 'ascjksdcvyp12nbvnzxcmgonbmbh12hjg23'
>>> re.findall(r'(p\d{2}).*(s|go)\D*(\d+)(?:\D*(\d+))*', string)
[('p12', 'go', '12', '23')]

>>> string = 'ascjksdcvyp12nbvnzxcmsnbmbh12hjg23'
>>> re.findall(r'(p\d{2}).*(s|go)\D*(\d+)(?:\D*(\d+))*', string)
[('p12', 's', '12', '23')]
```

- With `re.findall` we are only willing to get what are matched by pattern grouping `()`
- `p\d{2}` matches any two digits after `p`
- After that `.*` matches anything
- Then, `s|go` matches either `s` or `go`
- `\D*` matches any number of non-digits
- `\d+` indicates one or more digits
- `(?:)` is a non-capturing group i.e. the match inside won't show up in the output, it is only for the sake of grouping tokens

Note:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(p\d{2}).*(s|go)(?:\D*(\d+))+?', string)
[('p12', 's', '12')]

>>> re.findall(r'(p\d{2}).*(s|go)(?:\D*(\d+))+', string)
[('p12', 's', '23')]
```

I would like to use one of the above two as matching later digits is kind of a repeated task but there are problems with both non-greedy and greedy matches, hence we need to match the digits after `s` or `go` well, kind of explicitly.

Comment: I think it should be `p\d{2}` since you only want to find two digits

Comment: @cricket_007 OP said _any digit_ but showed two digits..thats why i am sticking with what they said first..and yeah, for two digits, you are right..

Comment: Thank you so much @heemayl, could you please explain what you're doing in the first solution please (a break down would be awesome!)? It would really help me improve my understanding of regexes!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, yes it is supposed to mean any number with 2 integers after p.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to match your line with a minimal pattern, as a test. Use `(grouping)` and `(?:nongrouping)` parens to capture the interesting parts and not capture the uninteresting parts. Store away what you care about,
then chop off the remainder of the string and search for numbers as a second step.

```
import re
simple_test = r'^.*p(\d{2}).*?(?:s|go).*?(\d+)'
m = re.match(simple_test, line)
if m is not None:
    p_num = m.group(1)
    trailing_numbers = [m.group(2)]

    remainder = line[m.end()+1:]
    trailing_numbers.extend(               # extend list by appending
        map(                               # list from applying
            lambda m: m.group(1),          # get group(1) from match
            re.finditer(r"(\d+)", remainder) # of each number in string
        )
    )

    print("P:", p_num, "Numbers:", trailing_numbers)
```